# moz box shadow option not reflecting in safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, safari

box-shadow effect is not working in my safari 5.1.7
I have tried with -moz-box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow also.. but safari is not even showing that options.

How to get box-shadow effect??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari 5.1.7 for windows is an old browser. The browser has been discontinued.

From wiki

> Safari 5.1.7, released on May 9, 2012, is the last version available for Windows

So, in other words, safari for windows does not have `box-shadow`. Two alternatives;

- Use a `.png` file to display the shadow.
- Use a solid border

My suggestion, don't bother at all. The browser is dead. Don't spend much time trying to make the shadows look beautiful.